# Bulk file move same file extension

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, file, onedrive, powershell-script

I need to move files with from user. Sharepoint.com to user.onedrive.com. I tried using the SharePoint Migration Tool but it’s giving an error. Can someone help me with the easiest way to code this?